# Which degrees of freedom estimate to use for two-tailed t-test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, degrees-of-freedom, two-tailed-test

I have two samples:

Sample A = businesses that have not received a grant

Sample B = businesses that have received a grant

Ua = population mean of survival rate for businesses in A

Ub = population mean of survival rate for businesses in B

na = sample size of A

nb = sample size of b

sa = standard deviation of survival rate in sample A

sb = standard deviation of survival rate in sample B

I want to test that the survival rate is different for businesses with a grant compared to those without. In other words:

H0: Ua-Ub=0

Ha: Ua-Ub =/= 0

I am using the following test statistic:

[image: test statistic for two-tailed test comparing means]

I am confused about what the correct degrees of freedom are. Some resources say it should be (na + nb -2) whilst others say it is the lesser of na-1 and nb-1. They both produce materially different degrees of freedom estimates when samples sizes are small. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Hi Jay. Welcome to Cross Validated. While mentioning about sources, it is a good practice to cite the references. Secondly, this is a MathJax enabled site; for a quick guide, please check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: Hi there. Sure that makes sense. Here is one source saying to use the lesser of na and nb:
https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/statistics/univariate-inferential-tests/two-sample-t-test-for-comparing-two-means
Here is another source saying different: https://vitalflux.com/two-sample-t-test-formula-examples/#:~:text=The%20two%20sample%20t%2Dstatistic,two%20data%20sets%20(H0).

Answer (score 0):

There is subtle difference between the statistic as used in the two sources. [One](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/statistics/univariate-inferential-tests/two-sample-t-test-for-comparing-two-means) didn't use the pooled variance estimator and the [other](https://vitalflux.com/two-sample-t-test-formula-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20two%20sample%20t%2Dstatistic,two%20data%20sets%20(H0)) used it.

Formally, under the assumption of equal but unknown variances, the statistic to be used for testing the difference of means is

$$t:= \frac{(\bar x_1-\bar x_2)-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{S_\text{pooled}\sqrt{\frac 1{n_1} + \frac 1{n_2}}}\sim \mathsf t_{n_1+n_2-2}.\tag 1$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if i have unequal and unknown variances which test statistic is the correct one? And how many degrees of freedom? I have seen the Welch's estimate for degrees of freedom (https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/types-of-t-test/unpaired-t-test/welch-t-test/) which is more complex but it approximates much closer to (na+nb-2). Is it ever correct to use "the lesser of na-1 or nb-1"? My ultimate goal is to calculate the power of the test for different sample sizes - the difference in deg of freedom is producing very wide results.

Comment: @Jay, if $\sigma^2_1/\sigma^2_2\ne 1,$ then you have to resort to Welch's test.